# Including a data folder in a python package using setup.cfg

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging

I have the following setup.cfg file, a usual project I want to publish to pypi and which should be shipped with a data folder, in my case ru_core_news_sm-3.1.0. (I am using setuptools):

```
[metadata]
name = test-project-name
version = 0.6.0

[options]
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.6
include_package_data = True
install_requires = 
    spacy==3.1.3
    beautifulsoup4

[options.package_data]
test_project_name/ru_core_news_sm-3.1.0 = *.*
```

This is my directory structure

```
base_project_name/
├── test_project_name
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── a.py
│   └── ru_core_news_sm-3.1.0
├── pyproject.toml
├── MANIFEST.in
└── setup.cfg
```

and I have this in my MANIFEST.in:

```
recursive-include test_project_name/ru_core_news_sm-3.1.0 *.*
```

I am testing the install by executing `pip install path/to/base_project_name`

However, this does not get me all files in the data folder, but only some of them, and I don't know why.

These are the files in the base folder:

[image: before]

and this is what remains when I have "test installed" it using pip to some other location (both projects use venv):

[image: after]

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem: You should not use `*.*` to include all files, but instead simply `*`. Because sometimes files don't have an ending, which will then get ignored. Depending on the file (MANIFEST.in):

```
recursive-include project_name/ru_core_news_sm-3.1.0 *
```

or (setup.cfg)

```
test_project_name/ru_core_news_sm-3.1.0 = *
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with **Setuptools 62.3.0**, you can now use **recursive wildcards** (`"**"`) to include a (sub)directory recursively. This way you can include whole folders with all their folders and files in it.

For example, when using a `pyproject.toml` file, this is how you include two folders recursively:

```
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"ema_workbench.examples.data" = ["**"]
"ema_workbench.examples.models" = ["**"]
```

But you can also only include certain file-types, in a folder and all subfolders. If you want to include all markdown (`.md`) files for example:

```
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"ema_workbench.examples.data" = ["**/*.md"]
```

It should also work when using `setup.py` or `setup.cfg`.

See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/3309 for the details.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I've used your [config](https://github.com/quaquel/EMAworkbench/blob/master/pyproject.toml) as a starting point. I've also converted my setup.cfg to pyproject.toml with `ini2toml setup.cfg -o pyproject.toml`. I now have dynamic version, and included data files in my wheels. And I finally removed setup.py and setup.cfg, which caused me many headaches.